# How many parallel executions can be done on a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, executable, remote-access

Hello we are planning to use a powershell script for some administrative tasks, which will be accessed by the remote admins. The script will be located on a central file share and will be accessed by all the remote admins via a small exe which simple points to and executes the shared script.(All this is for ability to alter script whenever possible without redistributing to all the admins).

So my questions are how many can access the script in parallel; would it crash if number of users is high? Are there any benchmarking techniques for this kind of process? Is there a better solution to this?

Please do let me know if any additions questions or clarifications required.

Comment: As long as the script is read-only, I believe the limit would most likely be set by the fileserver; how many sessions it support. When you run the exe it will load it to your local memory before running.

Comment: We have arround 250 admins and we estimate parallel of max 35-40 connections and the script it read only(executable).

Comment: Then your should be good. Unless you meant 35-40 connections per admin, hehe =) If the script is connecting to another service(a server of some kind), make sure that the server supports the amount of connections you expect(40).

Comment: This might sound dumb to many (but I've had a few people misunderstand this before) but you do realize that the script is just _content_ on the remote server, and it will actually be _executed_ on the caller's machine, not on the server where the script lies, right?

Comment: yes, we do realize that; we also have our taskpads(mmc's) on the file share which are initiated by the script. we are running the remote                  script with simple code on client workstation;                              `Powershell \\Server\$Fileshare\Script.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe each invocation of the script will run in its own runspace, so the only limit would be share connections permitted.

Hope this helps,
Chris